# Kubernetes: Label each graphic card on a node for being able to schedule a specific pod on that card

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have some nodes with different amount of gpu cards. I want to be able to assign a specific pod to a certain gpu card, something like a reservation when I am assigning a task to it.

I have already seen, that you can label a node like that:

```
kubectl label node nodaA project-type=ProjectA
```

But this is just labeling a node, which a pod will be assigned to it. But I want to be able to be more specific.

Let's say I have a node called **NodeA**, which has **3 GPU cards** from **Nvidia**. The first card is reserved for a specific task called "***CertainOne***", the other two cards are just there available for other pods.

When a user submits pods which is **not** the "***CertainOne***", the pods should be assigned to these 3 cards, no matter what label. But when another user submits a pod with the label "***CertainOne***", then  the reserved card should always be used (the other running pod which could be using at that moment should be dropped and the pod with the label CertainOne should use it as a priority)

But I wasn't able to find a solution for that. The whole idea is, that I can change the reservation card at anytime, for example to another card, but also to change the range, let's say not only the first one, but also the second one, so that pods with the label "***CertainOne***" should be assigned to card 1 or card 2 in this second scenario.

Is this even possible? Or is there another similar solution to that?

Comment: So far you can only specify on which node to schedule a pod. It's really rely on your app itself to choose on which GPU to run

Comment: I have a similar problem. I would like to be able to exclude certain GPUs from a certain node from being included in the cluster. For example, if I have GPUs 0, 1, 2, and 3 on the host, I would like to be able to make GPUs 2 & 3 available to kubernetes and reserve 0 & 1 for use by applications running on the host. Unfortunately, I have not yet been able to find a way to do this either.

Comment: I don't fully agree with @KenChen's comment, since it is possible to request an `nvidia.com/gpu` resource using NVIDIA's [k8s-device-plugin](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin), and then kubernetes will select a GPU for pod, but it doesn't seem possible to control which GPUs it will select from.

Answer (score 1):

> But this is just labeling a node, which a pod will be assigned to it.
>   But I want to be able to be more specific.
>
> But I wasn't able to find a solution for that.
>
> Is this even possible? Or is there another similar solution to that?

Unfortunately, as per my experience, I have bad news for you cause I have never seen solutions like what you want.
The very standard way is to use [`NodeAffinity`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity-beta-feature) in spike with appropriate labels and selectors. But this guarantee you scheduling pods on chosen nodes only and this doesnt fit you requirements :(

```
$ kubectl label nodes nodeA k8s-node=gpunode

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: runongpunode
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: k8s-node
            operator: In
            values:
            - gpunode
```